# How can I click list of elements in one frame (or) container?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]In this image I want to click view buttons as one by one that view buttons have same names. I am using list concept that is not working.[image]

Comment: Can you share the DOM code from the iFrame element to the View elements?

Comment: Anijith, as a new contributor, you may not know, but it's common to mark as "Accepted" answers that fully satisfy your questions. It both motivates the contributors and express that you already have your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium provides two methods to deal with iFrames.

You can search for a iFrame with id *IFRAME_ID*

```
driver.switchTo().frame(IFRAME_ID)
```

And you can return to the context of the root element:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Of course, you can chain iFrames:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(IFRAME_ID1).switchTo().frame(IFRAME_ID2)
```

Meaning you will enter in the iFrame with ID *IFRAME_ID2* which is inside the *IFRAME_ID1*.

If they were siblings, you would need to return to the default context:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(IFRAME_ID1);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(IFRAME_ID2);
```

After switching to a iFrame, you can use WebDriver and WebElements as if the only the DOM branches **inside the iFrame exist**.